# Is this question about scipy.minimize methods too broad? If so, which part should be narrower?

Tags: discussion

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37096900/3904031) about `scipy.minimize`. *I am looking for a minimization method in SciPy that does not use derivatives and allows for bounds. 1d will do for now*.

I've added a bit of information about what I'm doing, and where I've looked. So far I've come up empty handed. So I have asked here.

8 views have brought 2 close votes, but zero comments. These feel more like drive-by's than anything else.

**Q:** Is the question too broad? If so, which part should be narrower? Thanks!

*update:* a [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219055/3904031) has been posted - a pkg which does *precisely* what I have asked for. Luckily my question was not closed!